# Doctrine2 simple where clause issue

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

Short and Simple: From time to time we send gifts to some of our users. I have a `user` table and a `gift` table with a many-to-many relationship. I want to fetch all users which did NOT receive a particular gift.

The following query however returns me all users and the gifts they've received, with the particular gift excluded.

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('u, g')
        ->from('Application\Entity\User', 'u')
        ->leftJoin('u.gifts', 'g')
        ->where('g.id != = :giftId')
        ->setParameter('giftId', 2);
```

If a user received a particular gift, I want to exclude that user from the result set. Is this possible with Doctrine2?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to select all users, then exclude those who had your gift already:

```
SELECT
    u
FROM
    Application\Entity\User u
WHERE
    u.id NOT IN(
        SELECT
            u2.id
        FROM
            Application\Entity\User u2
        JOIN
            u2.gifts g
        WHERE
            g.id = :giftId
    )
```

In [`QueryBuilder`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) [API](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php), it looks like following:

```php
$qb1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb2
    ->select('u2')
    ->from('Application\Entity\User', 'u2')
    ->join('u2.gifts', 'g')
    ->andWhere($qb2->expr()->eq('g.id', ':giftId');

$users = $qb1
    ->select('u')
    ->from('Application\Entity\User', 'u')
    ->andWhere($qb1->expr->in($qb2->getDQL())
    ->setParameter('giftId', $giftId)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Also, I don't personally think the `QueryBuilder` is suited for this use case unless you have dynamic DQL. As you can see, the query gets quite complex, and at some point you're even falling back to `QueryBuilder#getDQL`, which builds the DQL string and makes recycling of `$qb2` impossible. 
Plain DQL works just fine here.